# Oracle query BETWEEN (date) AND (date)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

My table "Message" contain a column name : message_date (datatype : TIMESTAMP) which stores date and time. But in this case, I would like to only show the date of the data, so I use the method   **to_char(case(message_date as date),'DD-MM-YYYY')**

```
SELECT msg_id, msg_details, to_char(cast(message_date as date) ,'DD-MM-YYYY')as "DATE"
FROM message
WHERE message LIKE '%hi%'
AND to_char(cast(message_date as date), 'DD-MM-YYYY')
BETWEEN '15-01-2018'
AND '30-01-2018'
```

I would like to show only the row between the date **15-01-2018 and 30-01-2018**. But in the end, the query result came out with the data which from **date 15 - 30**..where row with other month (exp: **20-03-2018** also shown in the result. I not sure why it only check for the date and not together with month and year...
Seek for help ..thanks

Comment: Any string beginning with `'2'` is going to fall between the strings `'15-01-2018'` and `'30-01-2018'`, because `'2'` is between `'1'` and `'3'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use date literals with the dates in an ISO compliant format:

```
WHERE
    message LIKE '%hi%' AND
    message_date BETWEEN date '2018-01-15' AND date '2018-01-30'
```

Notr that you don't need to cast `message_date` to text, because it is already a timestamp and can be directly compared to dates.

Comment: @newlearner Sorry, I didn't read the rest of your query before answering.  Just compare `message_date` directly without casting to a date.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue with using `BETWEEN` when comparing dates is if one or more of the dates you're comparing has a time portion. For example, the date `30-JAN-18 01.32.32 PM` certainly isn't between `15-JAN-18` and `30-JAN-18` - it's greater (er, later) than the latter date. Plus while using `BETWEEN`, which is inclusive, there is always the chance of including an edge case you didn't intend. My recommendation would be to do something like this:

```
SELECT msg_id, msg_details, TO_CHAR(message_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS "DATE"
  FROM message
 WHERE message LIKE '%hi%'
   AND message_date >= DATE'2018-01-15'
   AND message_date < DATE'2018-01-30' + 1;
```

Notice in the first line I got rid of your `CAST()` - there is no reason to cast a date value to the `DATE` datatype. In the last line I'm using a bit of Oracle date arithmetic; this will give me all dates up to and including `30-JAN-18 11:59.59.9999....`.

As an aside you might want to apply the `LOWER()` function to `message` in your `WHERE` clause:

```
 WHERE LOWER(message) LIKE '%hi%'
```

otherwise you will miss messages containing `Hi`, `HI`, `hI`, etc.